# wrong 2nd Argument Type

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am implementing navigation drawer in my app and having a code as below

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


import com.example.project.project.TimeSheet.ObjectDrawerItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
        ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];

        drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.mipmap.timesheet, "Time Sheet");
        drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.mipmap.claims, "Claims");

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }


        private void selectItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment=new Information();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Claims();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm seeing a red line underneath `fragment`

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

When I point to the `fragment` , I get

```
Wrong 2nd ArgumentType.Found 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment', required 'android.app.Fragment';
```

And this is part of my Information activity

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Information extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Spinner spinner;

    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private com.example.project.project.API.InfoAPI ts;
    private static EditText txtDate;
    private DateDialog dialog;
    private static String a;
    private static String date1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information, container, false);
        dialog=new DateDialog();
        ts = new com.example.project.project.API.InfoAPI(getActivity());
        txtDate = (EditText) info.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        spinner = (Spinner) info.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        txtDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        addItemsOnSpinner();

        btnSaved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String date=txtDate.getText().toString();
                ts.insertTimeSheet(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(),date,spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        Button button=(Button)info.findViewById(R.id.button5);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), WorkForce.class);
                a = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                intent.putExtra("a",a);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


            return info;
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

    }



    public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

**LogCat error**

```
Error:(86, 80) error: incompatible types: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment
```

If I `import android.app.Fragment` to both activities, I get **incompatible types in my Information.java**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

    }
```

Comment: Guess you did the wrong import for the `Fragment` class.

Comment: Did  you mean I need to import android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Comment: That´s what the compiler tells you, that it needs to get a `Fragment` class from `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: I just edited..have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
getFragmentManager()
```

to

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: there are nothing wrong in  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();....If I change to  getSupportFragmentManager(), I get incompatible types

Comment: if you use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, must use  `getSupportFragmentManager()` for Fragment Manager and vice versa if you use `android.app.FragmentManager;` must use `import android.app.Fragment;` for Fragment.